# Using a keras model in a custom keras loss

Tags: tensorflow, keras, predict, loss-function

I have a regular keras model called `e` and I would like to compare its output for both `y_pred` and `y_true` in my custom loss function.

```
from keras import backend as K
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.square(e.predict(y_pred)-e.predict(y_true)), axis=-1)
```

I am getting the error: `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'ndim'`
This is because `y_true` and `y_pred` are both tensor object and `keras.model.predict` expects to be passed a `numpy.array`.

Any idea how I may succeed in using my `keras.model` in my custom loss function?

I am open to getting the output of a specified layer if need be or to converting my `keras.model` to a `tf.estimator` object (or anything else).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, let's try to understand the error message you're getting:

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Let's take a look at the Keras documentation and find the [predict](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#predict) method of Keras model. We can see the description of the function parameters:

> x: the input data, as a Numpy array.

So, the model is trying to get a `ndims` property of a `numpy array`, because it expects an array as input. On other hand, the custom loss function of the Keras framework gets `tensors` as inputs. So, don't write any python code inside it - it will never be executed during evaluation. This function is just called to construct the computational graph.

---

Okay, now that we found out the meaning behind that error message, how can we use a Keras model inside custom loss function? Simple! We just need to get the evaluation graph of the model.

### Update

The use of `global` keyword is a bad coding practice. Also, now in 2020 we have better [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) in Keras that makes hacks with layers uneccessary. Better use something like this:

```python
from keras import backend as K

def make_custom_loss(model):
    """Creates a loss function that uses `model` for evaluation
    """
    def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return K.mean(K.square(model(y_pred) - model(y_true)), axis=-1)
    return custom_loss

custom_loss = make_custom_loss(e)
```

---

### Deprecated

Try something like this (only for `Sequential` models and very old API):

```python
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    # Your model exists in global scope
    global e

    # Get the layers of your model
    layers = [l for l in e.layers]

    # Construct a graph to evaluate your other model on y_pred
    eval_pred = y_pred
    for i in range(len(layers)):
        eval_pred = layers[i](eval_pred)

    # Construct a graph to evaluate your other model on y_true
    eval_true = y_true
    for i in range(len(layers)):
        eval_true = layers[i](eval_true)

    # Now do what you wanted to do with outputs.
    # Note that we are not returning the values, but a tensor.
    return K.mean(K.square(eval_pred - eval_true), axis=-1)
```

Please note that the code above is not tested. However, the general idea will stay the same regardless of the implementation: you need to construct a graph, in which the `y_true` and `y_pred` will flow through it to the final operations.

---